# Clear views data in fragment on switching tabs in fragmenttabhost

Tags: android, fragment-tab-host

I am facing a issue and I have tried so many ways but none of the way worked for me. I am using fragmenttabhost for tabs. In one tab i.e SearchFragment tab there is edittext with the search button and bottom to it listview is shown.

Let's say I perform search, now the list is shown to me, now if I switch the fragment by clicking on another tab and comeback to search fragment still the list is shown to me with the text that I typed in edittext.

Requirement is: I want views to be empty when the fragment is open. I did debugging its going in onActivityCreated() everytime.

The code I am using is [this](http://paste.ofcode.org/fwhT6fbMyap5juiT5aGyz8)

Kindly see my code I am already using

```
etSearch = (EditText) getView().findViewById(R.id.etSearch);
        etSearch.setText("");
```

and in setDefaultValues()

```
universityArrayList.clear();
        contactArrayList.clear();
        adapterUniversity = new AdapterUniversity(getActivity(), universityArrayList);
        lvUniversities.setAdapter(adapterUniversity);
        lvUniversities.setSelector(new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#00000000")));
        lvContacts.setSelector(new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#00000000")));
        adapterContacts = new AdapterContacts(getActivity(), contactArrayList);
        lvContacts.setAdapter(adapterContacts);
```

Comment: override tab change listener and then detach the current fragment when tab is changed.

Comment: see this is my [TabsActivity](http://paste.ofcode.org/Z2AbDxPtQYLamdSczNTLvu) code, how to deatch tell please.

Comment: clear the data from edit text in onCreateView

Comment: I have already cleared that in initialiseViews() that i am calling in onActivityCreated()

Answer (score 0):

when you switch to the tab then onActivityCreated or in onResume you can write the below code to clear the edittext value

```
editTextSearch.setText("");
```

And refill the list with the same adapter data which you have used initially in the same method

```
ListAdapter customAdapter = new ListAdapter(this, R.layout.list_item, tempList); 
listview.setAdapter(customAdapter);
```

you can also used notifySetDataChanged() method to update data